# APDU always get response trailer SW1 SW2 = 0x67 0x00

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu

I'm working on PN5180 module to read data from my ePassport (ICAO 9303). I can send RATS - ATS, PPS, so technically, now i can exchange data using APDU command. Firstly, i tried to select LDS1 but however i tried, i always get SW1 SW2 = 0x67 0x00, which means "Wrong length".

Here my code trace:

RATS: 0xE0 0x80

ATS: 0E 78 77 D4 03 4D 4B 6A 43 4F 53 2D 33 37

PPS: 0xD0 0x11 0x00

PPS_resp: 0xD0

APDU_SELECT: 0x0A 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x0C 0x07 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x47 0x10 0x01

APDU_SELECT_resp: 0x0A 0x00 0x67 0x00

So maybe my INF in APDU_SELECT is incorrect, but the problem is i have used PN532 to communicate, i could read my ePassport with the same INF (using InlistPassiveTarget and InDataExchange).

If anyone see this post and worked with PN5180 or smart card before, pls let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure, what the first 3 bytes of your APDU_SELECT command mean (low-level protocol stuff?), but 6700 indicates a wrong length, which has no plausible intersection with a wrongly specified selection AID.

Comment: Because i have to implement ISO14443-4 protocol by myself, it's is I-block format(for Information exchange). 
It's PCB || CID || NAD || INF (APDU here) || 2CRC.

Comment: And thank you so much for replying my problem <3, i am very greatful.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means, that the trailing 1001 is the CRC. In that case the LC specification (07) should not include the CRC bytes and has to be reduced to 05.

Comment: oh no, sorry for not being clear. i did not write 2 bytes CRC in my trace, PN5180 (as some other NFC module like PN532) can automatic append CRC and check CRC when it gets response. I thought maybe the problem is this PN5180's fearture, but i have tried turn it off and implement it myself, still '67' '00' :(( (If CRC was wrong, the card won't response anything)

Answer (score 1):

To everybody who is stuck in this problem like me,

It was my fault because i have read the ISO14443-4 version 2001 but ISO has updated it to ISO14443-4 2018 version. So the difference is about the Block format.

Take a look at Block format, in v2018, it's appended one byte as the first byte of the Block. It's Length byte!, when v2001 doesn't include it in its Format.

That's why whatever i tried, my ePassport always take 0x0c (right before 0x07, which is the true Lc) as the Lc. So that, it returned '6700' "Wrong length" all the time.

[Link](https://cdn.standards.iteh.ai/samples/73599/78cb3949540b4b7da711f301650caa06/ISO-IEC-14443-4-2018.pdf) about ISO14443-4 2018.

Good luck to everybody read my post, thank you so so so much Maarten Bodewes!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a bit of a guess here; it may be the answer and it doesn't fit in a comment.

If you look at the I-block then the final nibble is defined as such:

- b4 : CID following, if bit is set to 1
- b3 : NAD following, if bit is set to 1
- b2 shall be set to 1
- b1 : Block number

I presume that this is the first APDU so the block number is probably the one initialized. However, as you both provide a CID and a NAT I presume that you need to set both of those to 1. That would make a nibble with value `1110` which translates to `E`, not `A`. To the card I would assume that the start of the APDU is off by one byte, receiving a `0x0C` instead of a `0x07` as Lc.

I don't see anything particularly wrong with the APDU, so I presume that the error lies outside of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for reading my problem <3 I have tried change the PCB byte to 0x0E, now the I-block to write to RF is:
APDU_SELECT: 0x0E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x0C 0x07 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x47 0x10 0x01.
But now, my MRTD doesn't rep anything.

Comment: Then i change the NAD byte to 0x01, still rep not thing, but if i don't send the 0x01 byte (last APDU byte) now the response is: 0x0e 0x00 0x10 0x67 0x00 0x26 0xcc. Again, still 0x6700

Comment: But at least, we had a little progress :))

Comment: maybe my ePassport has not completely read the entire message because of something in APDU_SELECT has being the "ending sign". Please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Nope, there is no ending sign. It is a SELECT (0xA4) by AID (0x04), where 0x0C indicates that no response needs to be send, followed by Lc, which encodes the Nc, the size of the command data (0x07). The rest is the AID of the passport (5 bytes RID of ICAO, the last two bytes indicate the application). The 0x07 and the fact that there is no Lr byte after the response data means that the length indication in the APDU itself is correct.

Comment: i have just realized that ISO 14443 has an upgrade. I think you and me have knowledge about ISO14443 the 2001 version, i have search for ISO14443 newest update, and it has a ISO14443 2018 version

Comment: The difference i want to know is about the Block format, so it say that now the block format is Length field || Prologue field || Information field || Epilogue field. Well, maybe now i have figure it out, that's why it always return "Wrong length" be cause it take 0x0c as Lc (as u said)

Comment: [link](https://cdn.standards.iteh.ai/samples/73599/78cb3949540b4b7da711f301650caa06/ISO-IEC-14443-4-2018.pdf) about ISO14443 (2018)

Comment: Hmm, I would be very surprised if it isn't backwards compatible, but one thing is certain: the APDU itself looks fine. And since you're implementing this yourself, I would be very surprised if the answer isn't in the ISO 14443-4 implementation. I was just quickly browsing through it, but I haven't spotted anything obvious (I didn't implement it myself though, so in that sense I'm not an expert on it).

Comment: thank you so so so soooo much, i was very upset because of spending too many time about this bug, your comments motivate me a lot.

Comment: Did it solve the problem? If not, please don't mark it as such! Otherwise others may get confused. If it has something to do with it then you can also edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, a "9000" is exactly what i expected!